# What is the difference: "part of" vs "part to"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

From the article in an exercise book: "There are 3 parts to the Canada parliament". What is the purpose of this "to", is it used only for giving specific intonation, or is it grammatically grounded? I'm guessing it's used for providing some "old-times" feel, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Note, "part of" has a meaning together as a phrase. This is just a special meaning of "to," meaning "makes up." The nearest I can find in Webster's is "used as a function word to indicate addition, attachment, connection, belonging, possession, accompaniment, or response." They give examples like "the key _to_ the door," which indicates belonging, but it can also indicate parts of a whole: "There are three steps to Granny's bread recipe."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If presenting a *complete* list, particularly a sequential list, "parts to" is more commonly used. E.G., "There are two *parts to* a sentence, subject and predicate."
- If discussing a *single* component, "part of" is more common. E.G., "Finland is now *part of* the EU."